# What is the correct formula for drift speed of electrons

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

[image]
These are the two formulae I came across for the drift speed of electrons in a circuit. Which one of them should I use for calculations? Which one is to be used for calculations?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please avoid posting screenshots of text. It's better if you type out the information using MathJaX because that helps users read the content on all devices and lets search engines index it.